# how to hover on multiple charts with the same x axis with plotly (Python)?

Tags: python, hover, plotly, subplot

I have figure with 2 subplots:  a candlestick stock chart and the volume bar chart associated below. I would like to hover on both charts when I move my cursor on one of them.
At the moment, the hover is only active on the subplot where the cursor is like in the screenshot[image: Stock Chart hovering on one subplot only]

I would like to activate the hover on volumes at the same time
I think it's possible to do it with Java, but I am not sure Python